# Hibernate REQUIRES_NEW or NESTED not working with MariaDB InnoDB

Tags: hibernate, mariadb, nested-transactions

I have a potentially long-running transaction in JBoss-EAP 7.2.6 where I need to commit in several steps.

I understand that MariaDB has no nested, but chained transactions.  This is my idea of how this should work:

```java
public class MyEntityManager implements IMyEntityManager {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "org.x.y.z")
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(timeout = 900) // 15 minutes
    public void doTransaction(MyEntity me) {
        // Spring has a misfeature that @Transactional only applies when called from the outside.
        // Calling through an external reference works around this shortcoming. :-(
        MyEntityManager self = this;

        self.persist(me);
        publish(me.id); // Pseudocode, my read-only client eagerly waiting for id.

        // Fill me with more data
        self.flush();
        // Fill me with more data
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void persist(MyEntity me) {
        em.persist(me);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void flush() {
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

I tried going to `NESTED`, and upgrading driver from 2.4.3 to 2.5.4 to no avail.

How to get such a scenario to work with InnoDB?  I'd be willing to issue a low level `COMMIT AND CHAIN` myself, as there seems to be no API for doing so in @Spring/Hibernate.

I tried

```
em.createNativeQuery("COMMIT AND CHAIN").executeUpdate();
```

but this leads to

```
XAER_RMFAIL: The command cannot be executed when global transaction is in the  ACTIVE state
```

while

```
em.unwrap(Session.class).createSQLQuery("COMMIT AND CHAIN").executeUpdate();
```

leads to

```
GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copying `this` to `self` (which I'd found elsewhere) is not enough.  It needs `self = applicationContext.getBean(IMyEntityManager.class)`.  Then `NESTED` throws unsupported.  Whereas `REQUIRES_NEW` does a complete transaction, after which `me` is no longer managed.

I have xa-datasources, and XA transactions don't mix with normal `commit`.  After I switched to a normal datasource, `em.createNativeQuery("COMMIT AND CHAIN").executeUpdate()` works like a charm.

Btw. I found in the C++ source code of Arjuna a method `chainTransaction` which doesn't seem to be exported to Java.  But I found it just does another `BEGIN` which seems to imply a `COMMIT`, so that might be the portable way to achieve this.